# Inline CSS style inside a php line

Tags: php, css, codeigniter

I have this code (CodeIgniter):

```
<tr>
    <td width="80">Gender*:</td>
    <td>
        <?php echo form_dropdown('gender', $gender_select, $gender_val); ?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo priv('gender',$profile_level['gender'])?>
    </td>                           
</tr>
```

Is it possible to have an `inline` CSS style inside the 'php line' to make its `height` or `width` be adjusted to any size I want?

Comment: It looks like you might be using a framework to generate the dropdown. Please specify which one so we can help with the syntax.

Comment: Wouldn't that be in the enclosing `<td>`? Or, in a relevant tag within `form_dropdown`, if that's a function you are able to change (say in the `<input>` or (if any) enclosing `<div>` tag).

Comment: im using codeigniter in this one..anyway thanks for those who replied, i got the solution earlier from @amccausl .:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a forth argument of the function (assuming [Codeigniter](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html)) which is a fragment of the tag

```
<?php echo form_dropdown('gender', $gender_select, $gender_val, 'style="font: 10px"'); ?>
```